# Get MAX element based on two different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have problem with SQL query on Oracle DB.. I have following tables:

```
DEPARTMENT(`ID` NUMBER(11), `NAME` VARCHAR(25))    
EMPLOYEE(`ID` INT(11), `LASTNAME` VARCHAR(25), `DEP_ID` INT(11));
SALARIES(`ID` INT(11), `EMPLOYEE_ID` INT(11), `SALARY` INT(11));
```

Now, I want to get name of depratment with highest average sum of salary. Department isn't directly related to Salaries so probably I need to use Employee table as well.

I've created a query:

```
SELECT NAME, (SELECT SUM(SALARIES.SALARY) FROM SALARIES JOIN EMPLOYEE ON EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID = EMPLOYEE.ID WHERE EMPLOYEE.DEP_ID = DEPARTMENT.ID GROUP BY EMPLOYEE.ID) AS AVG_OF_SUM FROM DEPARTMENT;
```

It returns list of department's name and avg sum. But now I need to get only one department name for the highest averange row.

Is my query actually OK? Or can be improved? And how can I get only one record?

Thanks for any help.

Regards,
D

Comment: What is a "highest average sum"?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the `ANALYTIC` function `SUM...OVER`

In the subquery, apply the analytic function, and then select only those rows which you desire.

For example,

`SELECT DISTINCT DEPT, SUM(SAL)  OVER (PARTITION BY DEPT ORDER_BY DEPT) SUM_SAL
FROM EMPLOYEE
ORDER_BY DEPT;`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NAME, (SELECT MAX(SUM(SALARIES.SALARY))
              FROM SALARIES
              JOIN EMPLOYEE ON EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID = EMPLOYEE.ID )
              WHERE EMPLOYEE.DEP_ID = DEPARTMENT.ID 
              GROUP BY EMPLOYEE.ID) AS AVG_OF_SUM FROM DEPARTMENT;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NAME, avg_sal FROM
    (SELECT d.NAME, avg(s.SALARY) avg_sal
      FROM SALARIES s
      JOIN EMPLOYEE e ON s.EMPLOYEE_ID = e.ID
      JOIN DEPARTMENT d ON e.DEP_ID = d.ID
    GROUP BY d.NAME
    ORDER BY 2 DESC)
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

(This query shows a department with the highest avg salary. If you need sum replace AVG -> SUM)